# Error at line:76 col:82 Line:76 ';' expected, got char[61]

Tags: xml

I was trying to set uri parameter and I always get the following error while i don't use any restricted characters.

> Error at line:76 col:82 Line:76 ';' expected, got char[61]

For example

`<value>smtp://authority.com?from=mymail@mail&username=user&password=pass</value>`

What is wrong with line as to result this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` character in XML must always be escaped as `&amp;`.